# UL LI how to remove padding?

Tags: html-lists

Is there a way to remove the empty space from just before list (where the blue line is on the picture)? I would be very grateful is somebody could help me with this.

```
<p class="has-text-align-justify"><b>List:</b>
<ul>
<li> Text1</li>
<li> Text2</li>
<li> Text3</li></ul>
</p>
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJcXi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p class="has-text-align-justify"><b>List:</b>
    <ul style="margin-top:-10px;">
        <li> Text1</li>
        <li> Text2</li>
        <li> Text3</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

Sorry. Forgot to add the changes

Comment: It's the same result as mine.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but adding the changes on the wordpress page, doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Try again! Add the ':' after margin-top. It should work. If it still doesn't, send the code of the whole div next time.